# How modify json file in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to save data in local , so I need to modify a JSON file, asyncstorage do this but how use it, I don't arrive to use method of React native:
JSON file

```
{
    "info" : [
        {"name" : "Quang Vi", "sex" : "male", "age" : 23, "hobby" : "sleeping"},
        {"name" : "Saitama", "sex" : "male", "age" : 25, "hobby" : "reading comic"},
        {"name" : "Songoku", "sex" : "male", "age" : 999, "hobby" : "eating"}
    ]
}
```

```
React Native
import React from 'react';
import data from './json/DATASS.json';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  const b = require('./json/DATASS.json');
  const a = b.info[0].name;

  console.log(a);




  return (
    <>

    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

I tried to use setItems or getItems, however I don't understand how to use it in my case.
Endeed I don't know what argument I can put in these methods.

I found new method, I don't arrive to use it :

````
  storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', 'stored value')
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
  }

  getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}

```

Maybe we can avoid to use it, the problem is that when I put this line:
```
b.info[0].name="Kodi"
```
The JSON file will not be modify.
Thank you very much.
````

Answer (score 0):

Your "b" constant is a string.
You need to first parse it into an object.
try:
`const c = JSON.parse(b)`
and then set "a" constant value based on your new "c" constant

Comment: When I added your code, that made me an error:SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object". I think it is already an object, I can't parse it.